# If window hash matches data-attr, addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following and I thought it would work, but I can seem to get a result.

```
if (window.location.hash === '[data-toggle-box="' + window.location.hash + '"]') {
            $("[data-toggle-box='" + window.location.hash + "']").addClass('active');
            console.log('works');
        }
```

Am I missing something small when it comes to verifying the value in a data-attr?

Comment: Remove `if`, just keep the `addClass` statement

Comment: that worked! thank you.  What about the if statement was breaking it? or does that just not with with a data-attr?

Comment: because `anyVar !== 'something' + anyVar`